# A complicated case of conditional line splitting to be performed in Vim

Tags: vim

Here is a sample of text that I’m working with:

```
Word1
Word2
...
Word4 / Word5 Word6
Word7
Word8 Word9 Word10 / Word11 Word12 Word13 Word14
Word15
Word16
...
```

I would like to transform it by splitting the lines containing
slash-separated chunks, so that the first chunk (preceding the slash)
gets the trailing words copied from the second chunk (following the
slash) to equalize the number of words in both lines resulting from
the chunks, if the former one has fewer words than the latter.

In other words, the desired transformation is to target the lines
consisting of two groups of words separated by a (space-surrounded)
slash character. The first group of words (preceding the slash) on
a target line has 1 to 3 words, but always fewer than the second
group.

Thus, the target lines have the following structure:

> **‹*G*<sub>1</sub>›** `/` **‹*G*<sub>2</sub>›** **‹*G*<sub>3</sub>›**

where **‹*G*<sub>1</sub>›** and
**‹*G*<sub>2</sub>›** **‹*G*<sub>3</sub>›** (i.e.,
**‹*G*<sub>2</sub>›** concatenated with **‹*G*<sub>3</sub>›**)
constitute the two aforementioned groups of words, with
**‹*G*<sub>2</sub>›** standing for as many of the leading words of the
after-slash group as there are in the before-slash one, and
**‹*G*<sub>3</sub>›** standing for the remaining words in the
after-slash group.

Such lines should be replaced with two lines, as follows:

> **‹*G*<sub>1</sub>›** **‹*G*<sub>3</sub>›**
> **‹*G*<sub>2</sub>›** **‹*G*<sub>3</sub>›**

For the above example, the desired result is as follows:

```
Word1
Word2
...
Word4 Word6
Word5 Word6
Word7
Word8 Word9 Word10 Word14
Word11 Word12 Word13 Word14
Word15
Word16
...
```

Could you please help me implement this transformation in Vim?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a `function` to `expand slash`:

```
fun! ExpandSlash() range
    for i in range(a:firstline, a:lastline)
        let ws = split(getline(i))
        let idx = index(ws, '/')
        if idx==-1
            continue
        endif
        let h= join(ws[ : idx-1])
        let m= join(ws[idx+1 : 2*idx])
        let t= join(ws[2*idx+1 : ])
        call setline(i, h.' '.t.'/'.m.' '.t)
    endfor
endfun
```

---

```
:%call ExpandSlash()
:%s@/@\r@
```

---

### before

```
1 2 3 / 4 5 6 7 8
```

### after

```
1 2 3 7 8
4 5 6 7 8
```

Comment: You've helped me sooo much you can't imagine. Hours of manual "sorting" are gone! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

One can use the following command to perform the desired transformation:

```
:g~/~s~\s*/\s*~\r~|-|exe's/\ze\n\%(\s*\w\+\)\{'.len(split(getline('.'))).'}\(.*\)$/\1'
```

This `:global` command selects the lines matching the pattern `/`
(here, it is delimited by `~` characters) and executes the commands
that follow it for each of those lines.

Let us consider them one by one.

1. The slash character with optional surrounding whitespace that
   separates the first and the second groups of words on the
   current line (as defined in the question’s statement), is
   replaced by the newline character:

   ```
   :s~\s*/\s*~\r~
   ```

   Here the tilde characters are used again to delimit the
   pattern and the replacement strings, so that there is no'
   need to escape the slash.
2. After the above substitution the cursor is located on the line
   next to the one where the substituted slash was. To make writing
   the following commands more convenient, the cursor is moved back
   that line just above:

   ```
   :-
   ```

   The `-` address is the shortening for the `.-1` range denoting
   the line preceding the current one (see `:help :range`).
3. The third group of words, which is now at the end of the next
   line, is to be appended to the current one. In order to do
   that, the number of words in the first group is determined.
   Since the current line contains the first group only, that
   number can be calculated by separating the contents of that
   line into whitespace-delimited groups with the help of the
   `split()` function:

   ```
   len(split(getline('.')))
   ```

   The `getline('.')` call returns the current line as a string,
   `split()` converts that string into a list of words, and
   `len()` counts the number of items in that list.

   Using the number of words, a substitution command is generated
   and run with the `:execute` command:

   ```
   :exe's/\ze\n\%(\s*\w\+\)\{'.len(split(getline('.'))).'}\(.*\)$/\1'
   ```

   The substitutions have the following structure:

   > `:s/\ze\n\%(\s*\w\+\)\{`***`N`***`}\(.*\)$/\1`

   where ***`N`*** is the number of words that were placed before
   the slash.

   The pattern matches the newline character of the current line
   followed by exactly ***`N`*** words on the second line. A word
   is matched as a sequence of whitespace preceding a series of
   one or more word characters (see `:help /\s` and `:help /\w`).
   The word pattern is enclosed between the `\%(` and `\)`
   escaped parentheses (see `:help /\%(`) to treat it as a single
   atom for the `\{`***`N`***`}` specifier (see `:help /\{`) to match
   exactly ***`N`*** occurrences of it. The remaining text to the
   end of the next line is matched as a subgroup to be referenced
   from the replacement expression.

   Because of the `\ze` atom at the very beginning of the
   pattern, its match has zero width (see `:help /\ze`). Thanks
   to that, the substitution command replaces the empty string
   just before the newline character with the text matched by the
   subgroup, thus inserting the third group of words after the
   first one.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I'll try to understand it... when I have some time

Comment: @OlivierPons:  In some sense, it is. :-)  I will add detailed explanation tomorrow.

Comment: Nice idea, could help beginners like me =)

Comment: @OlivierPons:  I have added an explanation of the proposed command.

Comment: Thank you very much this may be helpful for the community (including me!)

Answer (score 0):

For the given example the result is equivalent to replacing each `/` with the last word on the line and a line break `\r`. Here is a global substitute command to do it:

```
:%s#/ \ze.*\(\<\w\+$\)#\1\r#
```

Explanation:

- `/ \ze`    match the `/` end stop matching (nothing after the `\ze` will be substituted)
- `.*`       match any intermediate characters
- `\(`       start another match group
- `\<\w\+$`  match the last word before the end of the line
- `\)`       stop the match group

However, you then say that the trailing group `g3` may contain more than one word, which means the replace operation needs to be able to count the number of words before and after the `/`. I'm afraid I don't know how to do that, but I'm sure someone will leap to your rescue before long!

Comment: You forgot that the groups `g1` and `g2` may contain more than one word (but always the same number of words)

Comment: I think my command handles multiple words in `g1` and `g2`. All it does is replace the `/` with the last word, so the precise composition of `g1` and `g2` is irrelevant. (But as I said, it only works if `g3` contains a single word).